# Name of 60's Milton Bradley racing car game?

Tags: identify-this-game

Looking for the name of 60's Milton Bradley racing car game?

The game involved one wind up car, on the floor, no track, and each kid would have a pole that reached to the floor with a semi-circle piece of plastic on the end that would you 'catch' the moving car, it would go around the semi-circle, and go back to the other person.

I believe it may have also had a board.

(Was it just a dream? I have no more info but I do have good memories of it. Came in a standard board game size box.)

Comment: I don't think you're dreaming, I remember this too, though I recall it as a 1970s game with Hot Wheels size cars powered by a capacitor (charge from a flashlight battery in less than a minute).

Comment: I recall (dreamed?) that the cars has drivers.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of googling I think you might be looking for [Crash Canyon](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10968/crash-canyon)

It's publish by Milton Bradley and its has wind up cars.

It doesn't really fit the rest of the description but its possible you might have been playing your own game with the component cars.

Comment: Thank you but it's not it. My game was on the floor and the cars where something like Indy style circa 1964. Each had a plastic driver too.

I'm starting to think this was a dream.